# InOrderTraversal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tree-traversal, inorder

Can anybody explain to me what this error means?

I'm not looking for a solution but rather an understanding of the actual problem here.

```
const tree1 = {
  val: 1,
  left: null,
  right: {
    val: 2,
    left: {
      val: 3,
      left: null,
      right: null,
    },
    right: null,
  },
} as const;

interface TreeNode {
  val: number;
  left: TreeNode | null;
  right: TreeNode | null;
}

type InOrderTraversal<
  T extends TreeNode | null
> = T extends null
  ? []
  : [
      ...InOrderTraversal<T["left"]>,  // --> Type '"left"' can't be used to index type 'T', 
      T["val"],                        // --> Type '"val"' can't be used to index type 'T',
      ...InOrderTraversal<T["right"]>. // --> Type '"right"' can't be used to index type 'T'
    ];

type A = InOrderTraversal<typeof tree1>; // [1, 3, 2]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DbkY9aNp4TJnkA)

Thanks!

Comment: Explanation since Tobias has the answer covered: `T extends null` allows `T` to be `TreeNode | null`. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/w23AzN). That's why you must do the opposite, `T extends TreeNode`, and to prevent distribution, use `[T] extends [TreeNode]` as per my comment on Tobias' answer.

Comment: Thanks @caTS! Makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is probably the way type information is passed down in a conditional type. TypeScript knows that `T` has to be `null` in the true branch but inconveniently does not realize that the opposite must be the case in the false branch.

You said that you are not looking for a solution, but here is one anyway :)

```
type InOrderTraversal<
  T extends TreeNode | null
> = T extends TreeNode
  ? [
      ...(InOrderTraversal<T["left"]> extends infer U extends any[] ? U : never),
      T["val"],
      ...(InOrderTraversal<T["right"]> extends infer U extends any[] ? U : never)
    ]
  : []
```

I just switched around the conditional so that `T` is checked to extend `TreeNode`. Also note that this `infer U` stuff is needed to supress the `type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite` errors.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBTRBGGBeGBvAsAKBhgDcBDAGwC4YUAafQsxAMyirAFcyy6CZ4BLAOYALVtnqFi5KgCYekmIxZVcvBaUowAzPIWLmYjl10KBIw524TCAXxN8hotpd138NmCQgxQkKAG58fH4wKER4JhJgRBgAFSREADkQABMY1UINZwBbACNwwN4lMXjkZLSYAB8YIzJCwjMnOITymOrawpsgvCgATwAHGIBJMAB5eDT4eJIicIhyAB4JWJhEAA8wsBTvUqTUtprLfAA%20DDjVjcQtnZb9iQB%20GABta0kAOg%20AChHxyenZ%20DzMgLWJPABExTBAF1TutNtsYCEmOEYABVC7w7wkMC9J5QmCPdFsRAAgCU9kIoLBGmhFJgHze3zGE3C-zmiypjSg0Nhl2uiLAyPgaIxVwR2Nx%20MJMGJZNeUIkVDx3T6gxgAEEzj8WVN4DN2cDVYgQEw4AkUMd-DAAPTW560bQ0GAyKFAA)

Comment: You get `type instantiation is excessive...` because you are using distributive conditionals. If you suppress distribution with `[]`, then it'll work without the need to do the extra `infer U`: https://tsplay.dev/WJ5D5m